# Python MS Access Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I have an Access database that I want to interact with ipython

```
dataFile = "mydb.accdb"
databaseFile  = os.getcwd() + "\\" + dataFile

connectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=%s" % databaseFile

dbConnection   = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)

Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Did some research..
I am on 64-bits Windows 7 and I believe the python I am using is also 64-bits
I have also checked that I have `odbcad32.exe` under `C:\Windows\System32`

Answer (score 2):

Solution is simple...
Turns out that my Access is 32bit, so I downloaded Anaconda 32 bit and everything works now!